# UITableView Content size is not updated even after reload when I change its frame dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` whose frame is changing dynamically after I select a row. I set the new frame for this table view and reload it. But after reloading I am not able to scroll to all contents. Last 2 rows are not appearing. I have checked that 'numberOfRowsInSection' is returning correct value.
So, it seems like resetting the frame is somewhat disturbing the contentsize also of table view.

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: Please check Auto resizing and origin of UITable view in XIB.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem Generated Because If you change new Frame/design of `UITableView` then also made changes in UITableView and also your changeable Frame of UITableView is Bigger then your View So may be last two rows you can not be seem.

You need to set/update each Time frame of UITableView as.

```
myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(yourX, yourY, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - yourY);
```